# Block file overwrite with Apache2 WebDAV

Tags: apache, webdav

I am setting up an internal server that will permit anonymous file uploads to a specific directory with HTTP. Note that I'm trying to avoid implementing something that is based on Python, PHP, etc to keep this setup as simple as possible, as I may not be the one that ultimately supports this system in the future.

I have a basic setup working using Apache2's WebDAV module, but I also want to block overwrites of any files that currently exist. Does WebDAV have an extension for this?

Here is my current configuration script:

```
### Base HTML Directory
DIR_BASE=/var/www/html
mkdir -p $DIR_BASE
# Ownership
find $DIR_BASE -type f -exec chown root:apache {} \;
find $DIR_BASE -type d -exec chown root:apache {} \;
# Permission
find $DIR_BASE -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \;
find $DIR_BASE -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \;
# SELinux - Allow Apache to serve contents
chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t $DIR_BASE -Rv
### Upload HTML Directory
DIR_UPLOAD=/var/www/html/uploads
mkdir -p $DIR_UPLOAD
# Ownership
find $DIR_UPLOAD -type f -exec chown root:apache {} \;
find $DIR_UPLOAD -type d -exec chown root:apache {} \;
# Permission
find $DIR_UPLOAD -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \;
find $DIR_UPLOAD -type d -exec chmod 0775 {} \;
# SELinux - Allow Apache to write to directory
chcon -u system_u -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t $DIR_UPLOAD -Rv
### Web Service
# Upload Section
#  <Directory "/var/www/html/uploads">
#    Options None # Don't allow any secondary features, such as listing the files
#    AllowOverride None # Don't allow overrides from other configuration files
#    Allow from all # Anonymous Access
#    Require all granted # Anonymous Access
#  </Directory>
#  <Location /uploads>
#    Dav On # WebDAV for file upload functionality
#    <LimitExcept PUT> # Limit to file upload only
#      Order Allow,Deny # Anonymous Access
#      Allow from all # Anonymous Access
#    </LimitExcept>
#  </Location>
cat > /etc/httpd/conf.d/uploads.conf << _EOF
Alias /uploads "/var/www/html/uploads"
  <Directory "/var/www/html/uploads">
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  <Location /uploads>
    Dav On
    <LimitExcept PUT>
      Order Allow,Deny
      Allow from all
    </LimitExcept>
  </Location>
_EOF
restorecon -vF /etc/httpd/conf.d/uploads.conf
systemctl enable httpd
systemctl restart httpd
### Firewall
firewall-cmd --add-service=http --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Comment: What about using the SVN WebDav module? It would not necessarily prevent overwrites, but automatically version all your uploads so that any overwrittes could be undone.

Comment: That is a possible solution, but then requires the uploader to also use the subversion client. Ideally, the upload is as simple as a curl command (or equivalent). Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It's been a while since I tested that, but it is somehow possible to mount an SVN/WebDav page i.e. in Windows Explorer and then just drag and drop data.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution using the inotify-tools package. I had originally planned to use a simple cron job with batch processing, but with that package I could perform on-demand single-file processing. Given the relatively low volume of files I expect to receive, this should suit my needs well.

Everything is the same in my original script, but I have added the following:

```
### File Processing
PROCESSED=/data/processed
mkdir -p $PROCESSED
# Ownership
find $PROCESSED -type f -exec chown root:wheel {} \;
find $PROCESSED -type d -exec chown root:wheel {} \;
# Permission
find $PROCESSED -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \;
find $PROCESSED -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \;
# Bash Script
mkdir -p /root/scripts
cat > /root/scripts/uploadprocesser.sh << '_EOF'
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE=/var/www/html/uploads
PROCESSED=/data/processed

inotifywait -m -e create -e moved_to --format "%f" $SOURCE \
    | while read FILENAME
        do
            if [[ $FILENAME != ".davfs.tmp"* ]]; then
                echo "Detected $FILENAME, moving"
                mv --backup=numbered "$SOURCE/$FILENAME" "$PROCESSED/$FILENAME"
            fi
        done
_EOF
chmod +x /root/scripts/uploadprocesser.sh
# Systemd Service
cat > /etc/systemd/system/uploadprocesser.service << _EOF
[Unit]
Description=File Upload Processing Service
After=httpd.service
[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=root
ExecStart=/bin/bash /root/scripts/uploadprocesser.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
_EOF
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable uploadprocesser
systemctl restart uploadprocesser
```

And since mv includes a built-in file rotation system, it negated the need for me to block overwrites. The comment from PMF got me thinking along these lines, so thanks for that!

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls /var/www/html/uploads/
lost+found

[root@localhost ~]# ls /data/processed/
test1  test1.~1~  test1.~2~  test1.~3~  test1.~4~  test1.~5~
```